# How to update checkbox values using user input

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to have a piece of code that displays data from table, saves the data inside a checkbox which, if selected, posts it forward. But I am stuck on a problem with trying to select a different amount of quantity than the original, it will always select the maximum amount due to the checkbox being set to stone when the page is loaded, can I update the checkbox values in some way? The checkbox code looks like this:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $ordernumber );

  foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){

    $unitprice = $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity();

       echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" . " " . $item->get_name() . "  ,  " . $item->get_quantity() . " units" . " | " . $item->get_total() ."'>";
```

and this displays a choice of amount for quantities of 2 and more:

```
  if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
                echo "Amount: " . "<input type='number' name='numberqty' value='" . $item->get_quantity() . "'max='" .$item->get_quantity() . "' min='1' > " . "<br/>";
              }
```

this is how it's displayed on the site itself: (note, from top to bottom they mean "Product name" "Amount" "unit price" "total price of the products") [image]

After selecting the desired checkboxes the user would press a button that would direct them to the next site with the selected products from the earlier page

if 2 is selected by the user here I want the number on the next page be 2, and if 1 is selected then it would be 1. But right now even if 2 is selected, it will display 3 on the next page instead of the desired 2.

is there a way to make this work by updating the given amount into the checkbox value that was set before?

edit: as per request, for clearing up what I want it to do is. To allow me to select a quantity with input type number inside an already defined checkbox made with foreach, which saves the data inside the checkbox manually, the goal is to allow updating the value of the checkbox into one with the new quantity, which is set originally in this piece of code:

```
$quant = $item->get_quantity();
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" . " " . $item->get_name() . "  ,  " . $quant . " kpl" . " | " . $item->get_total() ."'>";
```

here is the full code of pages 2 and 3.

```
  <div class="Etusivu">
        <form action="" method="post" style="border:0px solid #ccc">
            <fieldset><legend><b>Tuotteiden palautus</b></legend>
              <div class="step">
            <legend>Askel 2/3</legend>
          </div>
          <br />
              <p class="important">Tilauksen tiedot</p>
              <br />
              <div class="valitse">

            <p class="important">Valitse kaikki tuotteet, jotka haluat palauttaa</p>
          </div>
            <hr>

            <script>
            //function for making a checkbox to check all checkboxes
            function toggle(source) {
              checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('productinfo[]');
              for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
              }
            }
            function checkboxupdate {
              document.getElementById("numberqty").value = "<?php " " . $item->get_name() . "  ,  " . "2" . " kpl" . " | " . $item->get_total() ?>"
            }
            </script>

              <input type='checkbox' onClick='toggle(this)' />

            <p class="selectall">Valitse kaikki tuotteet</p>

            <label>Tilauksessa tulleet tuotteet:</p>
            <br />


            <?php
            //Gets and displays data based on certain variables from the database, connects quantity and product name into one string in array
            $order = wc_get_order( $ordernumber );
            foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){
              $max = $item->get_quantity();
              $quant = $item->get_quantity();
              $unitprice = $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity();

              echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" . " " . $item->get_name() . "  ,  " . $quant . " kpl" . " | " . $item->get_total() ."'>";
              echo '<p>';
              echo __('Tuotteen nimi: ' ) . $item->get_name() . '<br>';
              if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
                echo "Määrä: " . "<input type='number' name='numberqty' value='" . $quant . "'max='" . $quant . "' min='1' > " . "<br/>";

              }
              else {
              echo __('Määrä: ' ) . $quant . '<br>';
            }
            if ($item->get_quantity() > 1) {

              echo __('Tuotteen kappalehinta: ') . $unitprice . '€' . '<br/>';
            }
              echo __('Tuotteiden kokonaishinta: ' )  . wc_price($item->get_total()) . '</p>' . '<br/>';

           }
            echo '<p>'. __('Tilauksen yhteishinta: ') . $order->get_total() . '</p>';
            echo "<button onclick='checkboxupdate()'>kokeile</button>";
            ?>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <input type="submit" id='check' value="Seuraava"/>
            <script>
            //Checks if any checkboxes have been checked, if not, displays an error
            function checkBoxCheck() {
              if($('input[name="productinfo[]"]:checked').length) {
                console.log("at least one checked");
                return true;
              }
              else {
                alert("Valitse vähintään yksi tuote.");
                return false;
              }
            }
            //runs the script for checking the checkboxes
            $('#check').on('click', checkBoxCheck);
          </script>

            </label>

            <div class="clearfix">
              <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2">

            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        <br />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>



 <?php
    //checks if the 2nd page submit button has been pressed successfully, if so continues to the next page
  } if ($page == 2) {
    global $wbdb;
    //prints errors, for debugging
    if($wpdb->last_error !== ''){
      $wpdb->print_error();
      //creates a new variable for later input of a comment within a textarea
      $comments = $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'];
  }
?>

<body>
    <div class="Etusivu">
        <form action="" method="post" style="border:0px solid #ccc">
            <fieldset><legend><b>Tuotteiden palautus</b></legend>
              <div class="step">
            <legend>Askel 3/3</legend>
          </div>
          <br />
              <p class="important">Palautuksen varmistus</p>
              <br />
              <div class="valitse">
            <p class="important">Haluatko varmasti palauttaa seuraavat tuotteet?</p>
          </div>
            <hr>
            <?php
            //Makes an array from given data from the previous page
            $test = $_POST['productinfo'];
            //variable for counting total price of the chosen items
            $total2 = 0;
            //variable for counting the total quantity of the selected items
            $totalquantity = 0;
            //Loop for displaying every selected product individually and their prices and quantities and adding each price and quantity to eachother to allow calculation of total price and quantity
            for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
            list($name, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);
            echo "Nimi: ".$name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Hinta: ".$total . "€";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br/>";
            $total2 += $total;
            $totalquantity += $quantity;
            $names[] = $name;

}
            //Sets the total price, quantity into a session
            $_SESSION['totalprice'] = $total2;
            $_SESSION['totalquantity'] = $totalquantity;
            //Uses Json encoding to set the array including the displayed names into session data to allow the displayment of each within the secondary form to insert the data into the database
            $_SESSION['product'] = json_encode($names, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
            ?>

            <br />
            <br />
            <h4>Kirjoita alas, miksi haluat palauttaa tuotteen/tuotteet?</h4>

            <?php

            //variable for textarea comment to allow insertion into database
            $comments = $_POST['comments'];

            //Inside textarea $comments displays the data inside it to save it and insert it into database that way?>
            <textarea id='commenter' name='comments' cols='30' rows='4' placeholder='Kirjoita tähän:'><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>

            <div class="refundprice">
              <?php //inside label is a $total2 variable which is the total price of everything that was checked and taken to this page ?>
            <?php echo '<label>Palautettavien tuotteiden yhteishinta: ' . $total2 . '€' . '</label>'
            ?>
          </div>
            <div class="clearfix">

           <input type="hidden" name="page" value="3">
          <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" name="sendrqst" value="Lähetä">
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php

  }

?>
```

Comment: Can you please describe in short what you want??

Comment: Can you post the full code here? I didn't understand your requirement.

Comment: In short, I want to be able to change a value inside an already created checkbox @bhanusengar

Comment: Added the full code of pages 2 and 3 (the ones that matter) to the original post @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: Did you intentionally not use `numberqty[]` instead of `numberqty` for the quantity field - you used `<input type='number' name='numberqty'` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ Would it help if I made it an array? the issue is after all that I cannot update the already existing data inside the foreach?

Comment: Yes, it would, in terms of it will give you the proper quantity selected for the corresponding product/item in the order. So if you change the quantity field's name to `numberqty[]`, on the next page (i.e. page 3), after `list($name, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);`, you can add for example `$quantity = $_POST['numberqty'][$i];`. Just give it a try and see how it goes..

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079357/change-or-update-checkbox-values-using-user-inputs

Comment: @SallyCJ Will check once I can.

Comment: @Marty1452 duplicate or not, neither one has an answer that worked so far.

Comment: Sure @Veraen, take your time.

Comment: @SallyCJ it does actually work like it is supposed to, I will see into implementing it in the way I wish, thank you very much this thing has been a thorn in my back for over a week now.

Comment: @SallyCJ You may make an answer version of what you said incase you want the bounty so I can award it to you.

Comment: Actually came across a different type of problem with this, if I select all of the checkboxes, it works just fine but if I have a product without a "numberqty" bar, it doesnt work properly for the rest, same if I only select the later checkbox with number selection it will display the one from the first number selector cause the $i will be wrong number. @SallyCJ

Comment: Okay I'll check that and get back later, or write a proper answer, @Veraen.

Comment: Thank you, I will be looking forward to the answer. @SallyCJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's "optimize" your `toggle()` function:

- ```
  function toggle(source) {
    // 1. Define `checkboxes` and `i` as local variables using the `var`
    // keyword.
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('productinfo[]'), i;

    // 2. I also "simplified" your `for` expression - no extra "n" here.
    for (i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
  ```

  or why not use jQuery:

  ```
  function toggle(source) {
    jQuery( ':checkbox[name="productinfo[]"]' )
      .prop( 'checked', source.checked );
  }
  ```

Now, pick and try one of these options, or both:

### Solution 1: JavaScript + PHP

I could see that you tried to use the `checkboxupdate()` function to dynamically update the `checkbox` value — or more precisely, the quantity that the user inputted in the quantity field. But it doesn't work because there are no elements with the `id` of `numberqty` and secondly, the PHP variable of `$item` there is undefined and will cause a fatal error. (And even if you got these fixed, you'll still need to adjust the code to make it actually works.)

*Note that this and the other solution are based on your format for the `checkbox` value — note the space at the beginning: `{item name}  ,  {quantity} kpl | {total price}`.*

1. On step #2, in the `foreach` loop, apply these changes:

   ```
   foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){
     // 1. Wrap the item inside this `div`.
     echo '<div class="order-item">';

     ... your code here ...
     // 2. For the quantity field, replace the name='numberqty' with
     //    class='numberqty'. I.e. use `class` instead of `name`.
     if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
       echo "Määrä: " . "<input type='number' class='numberqty' value='" . $quant . "'max='" . $quant . "' min='1' > " . "<br/>";

     }
     ... your code here ...

     // 3. Make sure to close the `div`.
     echo '</div>';
   }
   ```
2. Then use this `checkboxupdate()` which utilizes jQuery:

   ```
   function checkboxupdate() {
     jQuery( ':checkbox[name="productinfo[]"]' ).each( function() {
       var $order_item = jQuery( this ).closest( '.order-item' ),
         $qty = $order_item.find( 'input.numberqty' );

       if ( $qty.length ) {
         jQuery( this ).val( this.value.replace(
           /\d+ (kpl \| [0-9\.]+)$/,
           ( $qty.val() || 1 ) + ' $1'
         ) );
       }
     });
   }
   ```
3. And <strike>if necessary (because your `$name` below already contains the quantity),</strike> on step #3, in the `for` loop, you can get the quantity (without the unit or the text `kpl`) like so:

   ```
   for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
     list($name, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);

     // 1. Retrieve the preferred refund quantity.
     list( $name2, $quantity ) = explode( ' , ', $name );
     $quantity = intval( $quantity ); // strips the " kpl"
     echo 'The quantity: ' . $quantity . '<br>'; // test

     ... your code here ...
   }
   ```

And for the button which calls the `checkboxupdate()` function, make sure that the button `type` is set properly — if you don't, it defaults to a submit button, and clicking on it will submit the form instead of just updating the `checkbox` value:

```
<button onclick='checkboxupdate()' type="button">kokeile</button>
```

or append `return false;` to the `onclick` attribute to prevent the default action:

```
<button onclick='checkboxupdate(); return false'>kokeile</button>
```

### Solution 2: PHP-only

Note that this is just one of the different ways you can bring the quantity selected on to the next page (or from step #2 to step #3). And with this option, you would just ignore the `checkboxupdate()` *and* the button that calls the function.

1. Make these changes in the `foreach` loop on step #2:

   ```
   // 1. Add the `$i => `
   foreach ($order->get_items() as $i => $item ){
     ... your code here ...

     // 2. Add the `; $i` to the value - at the end.
     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" . " " . // wrapped
       $item->get_name() . "  ,  " . $quant . " kpl" . " | " . $item->get_total() ."; $i'>";
     ... your code here ...
     // 3. Change the `name` to numberqty[ $i ].
     if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
       echo "Määrä: " . "<input type='number' name='numberqty[" . $i . "]' value='" // wrapped
         . $quant . "'max='" . $quant . "' min='1' > " . "<br/>";

     }
     ... your code here ...

   }
   ```

   *Or just remove the `"  ,  " . $quant . " kpl" .` from the `productinfo` field, where the markup would be:*

   ```
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" . " " . // wrapped
     $item->get_name() . " | " . $item->get_total() ."; $i'>";
   ```
2. *Before* the `for` loop on step #3, add the `$qty_array` variable as you can see below, then make the other changes *inside* that loop:

   ```
   // 1. Retrieve all the POSTed numberqty values.
   $qty_array = isset( $_POST['numberqty'] ) ? (array) $_POST['numberqty'] : array();

   for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
     list($name, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);

     // 2. Retrieve the preferred refund quantity.
     list( $total, $index ) = explode( '; ', $total );
     $quantity = isset( $qty_array[ $index ] ) ? intval( $qty_array[ $index ] ) : 1;
     echo 'The quantity: ' . $quantity . '<br>'; // test

     // 3. Update the quantity in the item *name*.
     list( $name ) = explode( ' , ', $name );
     $name .= ' , ' . $quantity . ' kpl';

     echo 'Nimi: ' . $name . '<br>';
     ... your code here ...
   }
   ```

   *If you removed the `"  ,  " . $quant . " kpl" .` from the `productinfo` field, ignore the following `list()`:*

   ```
   //list( $name ) = explode( ' , ', $name ); // purposely commented out
   ```

And that's really all you need, no custom JavaScript necessary.

Comment: This worked like a charm, the php only one managed to fix all the issues within the cursed quantity selection, thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad it helped you. =) And sorry if I got the `checkboxupdate()` / "kokeile" thing wrong.. I just thought I should also give you the JS + PHP option, but it's certainly not a priority despite it's the first solution I suggested. :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the `checkboxupdate()` was wrong either, I might've done it wrong but it was also pretty nice of you to actually translate (or so I suppose since there was no "kokeile" what I could see in the original code) to match the language too, it's also the most important part that one of the fixes worked at the very least.

Comment: If (and only if) you want, I can just remove the JS + PHP solution from the answer? And actually, there's one more possible solution - and could be better in terms of users wouldn't be able to mess with the total price in the checkbox value - where we bring the order number to the next step (#3) and use the same `foreach` (I mean the `$order->get_items()`) as on step #2. Would you like to see it?

Comment: Sure if you would like to make add it, and there's no need to remove the JS + PHP method, it might work for someone else in the future after all.

Comment: oh and the total price shouldn't be able to be messed with even now, cause I recalculate it anyways on the page 3 after all using the quantities and unit prices.

Comment: In that case, then let's keep the answer as it is. :) (I was just concerned that you might "not liking" that extra JS + PHP option since the question wasn't tagged with "javascript" or "jquery"...) Cheers!

Comment: I probably just forgot to add the Javascript tag into the question in the beginning, thinking I could do it with just php. Cheers to you too for helping me to finally get over this problem!